# Column naming for an attribute which can have at most two values

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have an abbreviation field in a table for institutions. Each institution has one abbreviation at least. Some institutions can also have a second abbreviation. Rather than creating another table for normalization, I want to create two columns for each but don't know how to name them.

I can name as `abbreviation_1` and `abbreviation_2` but since I usually get the first one only in my sqls, I don't want to call the first one as `abbreviation_1`.

I can name as `abbreviation` and `abbreviation_2` which seems inconsistent, because in other tables I keep ISO country codes as `iso_code_2` for two character codes and `iso_code_3` for three character codes.

Is there a preferred way for this?

```
CREATE TABLE institution (
    ....
    abbreviation VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    abbreviation??? VARCHAR(10),
    ....
)
```

Comment: 2 columns is worse than 2 tables.

Comment: there will be at most two variants and that is for a few institutions, so 99% of records will be just for the first abbreviation and I will need to join to get the name. Still is it preferable?

Comment: If you ever need to check both abbreviations, you will find _that_ query to be clumsy.  My comment is not a hard-and-fast rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two different tables:

```
create table institution (
    institutionId int auto_increment primary key,
    . . .
);

create table institutionAbbreviations (
    institutionAbbreviations int auto_increment primary key,
    institutionId int,
    abbreviation varchar(10),
    foreign key (institutionId) references institutions(institutionId)
);
```

You will find that this simplifies your queries, unless the abbreviations are really different things (such as 2- and 3-character country codes).

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion keep  a `type` column in that table

```
CREATE TABLE institution (
    ....
    abbreviation VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    type VARCHAR(10),
    ....
)
```

Then you can keep differnet  `abbreviation` according to type

Comment: There can be two abbreviations at the same time, so this doesn't seem feasible for this case.